# Jquery mobile: redirect to another page before loading

Tags: jquery, redirect, jquery-mobile

am using jquery mobile 1.0

I want to redirect from ***first.html*** to ***otherPage.html*** without showing content of ***first.html***

```
$("#pageId").live("pagebeforecreate", function(event) {                 

  window.location.href = "otherPage.html";              

});
```

-i tried  almost every event, but not succeed. The ***first.html*** is shown up for a moment.

Then, I tried with 'pagebeforeload' event, but it isnt triggered

```
$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeload", function( e, data ){ 

        console.log("pagebeforeload starting"); // NO LOGGING HAPPENING 
        window.location.href = "otherPage.html";

        e.preventDefault(); 

        data.deferred.resolve( data.absUrl, data.options, response.page); 

}); 

$( document ).bind( "pageload", function( e, data ){
    console.log("Page successfully loaded into DOM..."); // NO LOGGING HAPPENING 
});
```

-am not much clear about this event & didn't find a workable example for it.
-Can anybody plz help!

Comment: Did you find the answer..  I need the solution.. THanks in advance..

Comment: Hi. Actually I did that almost 1 year ago. But will search & let u know.

Comment: I am doing the redirection from previosPage.html, to EITHER first.html OR otherPage.html. So the redirection-logic is now in previosPage.html

Answer (score 12):

Try This One

```
$("#firstPageId").live("pagecreate",function(){
         $.mobile.changePage("otherPage.html");
});
```

Also, You can use **loadPage**

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

The pagebeforeload event is only triggered when external pages are loaded in:

> Whenever an external page is loaded into the application DOM, 2 events are fired. The first is pagebeforeload. The 2nd event will be either pageload or pageloadfailed.

My only idea to get around this would be to load the page contents of **first.html** asynchronously, which isn't ideal because you end up making 2 http requests for the same page. However this will give you the ability to only call the **first-contents.html** if it's needed, otherwise you can redirect to **otherPage.html** without anything showing. eg:

```
<script>
    someCondition=true;
    if(someCondition) {
        window.location.href = "otherPage.html"; 
    } else {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').load('first-content.html', function() {
                //other stuff after the contents have loaded: like the rest of your jquery relating to first.html
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Make sure the body tags are empty in the **first.html** page.

Comment: I can only comment on my own answer atm; but I did try @Endophage's answer before posting mine however it still displays the page before redirecting on mobile devices for some reason, especially on first load (ie no cache) and larger page sizes.

Comment: Thnx for reply. only I want is- an event, in which the redirect will fire & further page load will stop. Else, Its easier to just show/hide the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply not using an event.  JS code will get executed as it is encountered so making sure your conditional code is at the top of the page (in the head somewhere) should be enough.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  if (condition)
  {
    window.location.href = "otherPage.html";
  }
</script>
<!-- rest of page -->
```

Comment: thnx for reply. But its not worked, this page flashed before redirection :(

Comment: @AvisekChakraborty Well that's about the best you can hope for with JS so if it isn't working you have 2 choices.  Either accept that it's good enough, or work out how to do the redirect server side...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish. Like Endophage states, you can do a simple JavaScript redirect if all you want to do is go to a different page.

I'm assuming that you want to be able to choose whether to display the contents of the first or second page but still stay on the first page.

You can add the following code. Make sure you add it **before** you include jquery.mobile.

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        // disable autoInitialize
        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
    $(function () {
        var displaySecondPage = true;
        if (displaySecondPage) {
            // load page2.html and replace #page1 with contents of #page2 on page2.html
            $('#page1').replaceWith($('<div />').load('page2.html #page2', function() {
                // continue initialize
                $.mobile.initializePage();
            }));
        }
        else {
            // continue initialize
            $.mobile.initializePage();                
        }
    });
</script>
```

Basically we bind to `mobileinit` so we can disable `autoInitialize`. This gives us more control of when to display the first page.

Now we can use a standard jQuery ready handler to test for our condition, and if true, load the contents of page2.html and replace the `#page1` page. Notice I'm using the `$.load` method with the page fragment syntax. This means you have to know the page id you want to load.

Once the page is loaded, you can call `$.mobile.initializePage` to allow jquery mobile to render the new page.

To prevent the contents of the first page to display during this load, I add the following CSS in my stylesheet:

```
div[data-role='page'] {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery Mobile takes care of showing and hiding pages, so making them all hidden by default will ensure you don't get a flash of unenhanced content.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<head> 
    <script>
        window.location.replace('otherPage.html');
    </script> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I spent some time trying to solve that, so this might be useful to somebody.

Now, with jquery mobile 1.3, you can simply set data-url to the `<div data-role="page" data-url="...">` on the target page. JQM will detect that and update urls accordingly.

See more here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-links.html

And even some demo here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/redirect/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like there are very answers to this; especially when you are using a multi-page template .. here's a link to an answer on jquery mobile forms that does work by injecting the # tag into the url before page init

[jquery forum answer](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-selection-a-start-page)

Doesn't work in my case since I don't want the user viewing the hash tag but it's a start .. more to come later